# Different hover effects on the same id

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a header with titles and a shopping cart. I want different hover effect on the titles and the cart.

```css
#menu-links {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#menu-links#title:after {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px violet;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%
}

#menu-links#title:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

#menu-links#cart:hover {
  color: violet;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link-main" id="menu-links title">Начало</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link-main" id="menu-links title">Lórèal Professionel</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link-main" id="menu-links title">Стайлинг</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link-main" id="menu-links title">Steam Pod</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link-main" id="menu-links cart"><svg
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-cart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
                            </svg></a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried to set 2 id's, but it did not work it broke more. Can someone help <3

Comment: You can't have multiple IDs on an element. Use class instead.

Comment: And  IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Variable and use it on hover. Use JavaScript and fetch that CSS variable and use addEventListener to listen on onmousehover event and when you hover on item then change the css variable color every time.

Answer (score 0):

The [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) value cannot be used more than once and it cannot contain whitespace.

As already commented, you should use CSS classes instead of id.

```css
.nav-link-main {
  /* position: relative; */
  color: white;
  /* font-size: 17px; */
}

.nav-link-main.title:after {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px violet;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%
}

.nav-link-main.title:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.nav-link-main.cart:hover {
  color: violet;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link-main title">Начало</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link-main title">Lórèal Professionel</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link-main title">Стайлинг</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link-main title">Steam Pod</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link-main cart">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
    </svg></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can assign duplicate IDs or even multiple values to the id attribute.
But you shouldn't do this, because **it undermines the concept and benefits of IDs.**

Currently, you're using IDs just like classes – **better use classes**

### Common usage for IDs

- IDs can be used for selecting unique elements by ID via javaScript (e.g for unique buttons like a mobile nav toggle button) in the most efficient performant way
- you can also use them for anchor targets - e.g scroll to a section with a specific ID

### Hacky approach using attribute selectors

However, you could style elements as described in your example using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none
}

[id*="menu-links"] {
  font-size: 32px;
}

[id*="cart"]:hover {
  color: violet
}

[id*="title"]:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: solid 3px violet;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%
}

[id*="title"]:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

svg {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link-main" id="menu-links title">Начало</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link-main" id="menu-links title">Lórèal Professionel</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link-main" id="menu-links title">Стайлинг</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link-main" id="menu-links title">Steam Pod</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link-main" id="menu-links cart">
      <svg fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
      </svg> Cart
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In fact, we're "degrading" the  otherwise **highly specific ID** (if we were selecting via `#menu-links`) to an arbitrary attribute selector like `[id*="menu-links"]`.

Better use classes for you nav an stick to commonly used best-practices.

#### Further reading

- [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)
- [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)